# Embed html/javascript/css in java/c++/python

Tags: java, javascript, html, embed

So, I have a fully functioning html/javascript/css web app, not sure if that's the right term, it works fine and dandy in a web browser.

The thing is I now have to move it **OUT** of a browser, **OFFLINE**, and to the "desktop", make it a standalone app. I would have to somehow wrap it in java/c++/python something, to make it run like that.

I really like Java since that is the language I know out of that list. I have looked into [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) & [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko/Embedding_Mozilla/Roll_your_own_browser). I haven't really found anything that is a nice plug and play. Like here is my .html file now run with it. I assume it would have to be in a swing window or something too.

Any hints/help/comments?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap it? Does your web app communicate with the server?

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm) out for a basic java browser.

Comment: @Frxstrem That worked like a charm. If you want to submit an answer similar to your comment I would be more than happy to accept it as the correct answer! Thank you!

Comment: @Sasquatch3o3 Glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As per request, I reposted my comment as an answer.)

The [Atom](http://atom.io/) editor is built using only web technologies, and uses the [Electron](http://github.com/atom/electron) framework (based on the Chromium browser) to run as a standalone application, with no external browser dependencies.

[It looks very easy to set up something similar yourself](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-distribution.md), and basically just requires you to put your files in a special directory. (Electron uses a lot of space, though, so it may not be practical for distributing applications below ~20 MB.)

Answer (score -2):

If you are really looking for an option where you just point at your current html and are off then you might just want to configure run a local web-server.  It changes almost nothing about how you are running your application except where it is being served from.

Comment: Not sure why so negatively rated, I was merely pointing out that if the OP really wanted to emphasize "Like here is my .html file now run with it."  he may well consider this as an option.  It does however go against his desire of moving out of the browser, so that also needs to be considered.